# If the value of a polynomial is $0$ for $x=1$ , why do we say that $(x-1)$ is a factor

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

My polynomial function is $x^3 + 3x^2 - x -3$

I'm trying to factorise this, can you please tell me how $x-1$ is a factor if $x=1$ gives a value of zero

Comment: You can use Ruffini's rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruffini%27s_rule

Comment: @mfl I simply want to know why/how  is x-1 a factor when x=1 gives 0 value , I don't have any problem factorising the polynomial

Comment: @PizzaThug Everything is explained in the skyking's answer. But if you want a name, it is know as [*polynomial remainder theorem*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem) (or [*little Bézout's theorem*](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Little_Bézout_Theorem)).

Comment: Thanks everyone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You see this by doing long division, by dividing with a polynomial of degree one you will get a constant remainder. That is you can write your polynomial as

$$p(x) = x^3 + 3x^2 - x -3 = q(x)(x-1) + C$$

Where $q$ is a polynomial and $C$ is a constant. Now consider this equation especially for $x=1$:

$$0 = p(1) = 1^3 - 3\cdot1^3 - 1 - 3 = q(1)(1-1) + C = C$$

so we see that $C=0$ and therefore your polynomial is $(x-1)q(x)$ which means that $(1-x)$ is a factor of the polynomial.

---

In general and more detail: If you have a polynomial $p(x)$ and a value $a$ you have that you can write $p$ as

$$p(x) = (x-a)q(x-a) + r(x)$$

for some polynomials $q$ and $r$ and we will always then have that $p(a) = r(a)$.

You also have that you can select $r$ to be of degree $0$ (that is a constant that will be the value of $p(a)$), this follows from the fact that if $r$ is of higher degree you can always find $r$ of lower degree. To see this you write $r$ as:

$$r(x) = \sum_0^N r_jx^j = r_N(x-a)x^{N-1} + r_Nax^{N-1} + \sum_0^{N-1}r_jx^j = r_N(x-a)x^N + \tilde r(x)$$

where $\tilde r$ is a polynomial of degree $N-1$ so you then can write $p$ as

$$p(x) = (x-a)\left(q(x) + r_Nx^{N-1}\right)+\tilde r(x) = (x-a)\tilde q(x) + \tilde r(x)$$

Where $\tilde q$ is another polynomial. Repeating this will eventually lead to a remainder of degree $0$.

Comment: Thank a lot kind sir!

Answer (score 2):

Let $P(x):=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ and let us develop $P((x-1)+1)$ using the Binomial theorem. We will get

$$P((x-1)+1)=a((x-1)+1)^3+b((x-1)+1)^2+c((x-1)+1)+d\\
=a'(x-1)^3+b'(x-1)^2+c'(x-1)+d'$$ for some new coefficients $a',b',c',d'$.

Then with $x=1$, $$P(1)=d'=0$$ and the polynomial is

$$(a'(x-1)^2+b'(x-1)+c')(x-1).$$

Answer (score 0):

We are trying to factorise $$x^3+3x^2-x-3=0$$

We can say that $$x^3+3x^2-x-3=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)=0$$ where $a,b,c$ are the roots of the equation.

We know that, for $pq=0$, that we must have $p=0$ or $q=0$ or $p=q=0$.

Therefore, we can say that at least one of $(x-a),(x-b),(x-c)$ must be $0$.

If $x-a=0$ then $x=a$, and we can see that if $x=a$ then \begin{align}f(a)&=(a-a)(a-b)(a-c)\\
&=0(a-b)(a-c)\\
&=0\end{align} and hence $(x-a)$ is a root of the equation.

Similarly for $x=b$ and $x=c$.

Comment: Why do we know that the cubic polynomial can be factored into a product of three linear factors in your second line? I know it's a well-known fact, but in my opinion that is really the heart of this question, and therefore cannot just be implicitly assumed.